# How to inject CacheItemPolicy using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am following some practices [documented](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) by [steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) and using [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/). I have a query that retrieves data from a WCF service and I want to cache the result using an instance of `ObjectCache`.

I've defined a decorator `CachingQueryHandlerDecorator<TQuery, TResult>`:

```
public sealed class CachingQueryHandlerDecorator<TQuery, TResult>
    : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> _handler;
    private readonly ObjectCache _cache;
    private readonly CacheItemPolicy  _policy;
    private readonly ILog _log;

    public CachingQueryHandlerDecorator(IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> handler,
                                        ObjectCache cache,
                                        CacheItemPolicy policy,
                                        ILog log)
    {
        _handler = handler;
        _cache = cache;
        _policy = policy;
        _log = log;
    }

    public TResult Handle(TQuery query)
    {
        var key = query.GetType().ToString();
        var result = (TResult) _cache[key];
        if (result == null)
        {
            _log.Debug(m => m("No cache entry for {0}", key));
            result = (TResult)_handler.Handle(query);
            if (!_cache.Contains(key))
                _cache.Add(key, result, _policy);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Within `SimpleInjectorInitializer.cs` I define the cache and policy, and add the decorator for a specific query:

```
container.RegisterSingle<ILog>(LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger());
container.RegisterSingle<ObjectCache>(() => new MemoryCache("MyCache"));
container.RegisterSingle<CacheItemPolicy>(() => new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1) } );
.
.
.
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>),
    typeof(CachingQueryHandlerDecorator<,>),
    ctx => ctx.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(MyQuery));
```

The problem I'm facing is that I want to be able to specify different `CacheItemPolicy`'s for different queries. I could create a new `ICachePolicy<TQuery>` interface and then define concrete classes for each different query type but I'm hoping there might be a way to avoid that and define the policy per query directly in the initialization file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I could create a new ICachePolicy interface and then define
>   concrete classes for each different query type

I think that's a pretty neat idea actually. You can register a default generic implementation that injected into every decorator that has no specific implementation registered:

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(ICachePolicy<>), typeof(DefaultCachePolicy<>),
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

And for queries that have an alternative cache policy, you can register a specific implementation:

```
container.RegisterSingle<ICachePolicy<MyQuery>>(new CachePolicy<MyQuery> 
{
    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHour(2)
});
```

Another option is to mark queries or their query handlers with an attribute that describes the caching policy (this is the route I usually take):

```
[CachePolicy(AbsoluteExpirationInSeconds = 1 * 60 * 60)]
public class MyQuery : IQuery<string[]> { }
```

Now you don't have to inject an `ICachePolicy<T>`, but can read this metadata directly using reflection:

```
public sealed class CachingQueryHandlerDecorator<TQuery, TResult>
    : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    private static readonly bool shouldCache;
    private static readonly CachingPolicySettings policy;

    private readonly IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> _handler;
    private readonly ObjectCache _cache;
    private readonly ILog _log;

    static CachingQueryHandlerDecorator()
    {
        var attribute = typeof(TQuery).GetCustomAttribute<CachePolicyAttribute>();

        if (attribute != null)
        {
            shouldCache = true;
            policy = attribute.Policy;
        }
    }

    public CachingQueryHandlerDecorator(
        IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> handler,
        ObjectCache cache,
        ILog log)
    {
        _handler = handler;
        _cache = cache;
        _log = log;
    }

    public TResult Handle(TQuery query)
    {
        if (!shouldCache)
        {
            return this._handler.handle(query);
        }

        // do your caching stuff here.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It occurred to me subsequently that creating the `ICachePolicy` interface would provide greater flexibility, particularly if I wanted to pull caching policies from a config file rather than hard coding them into the bootstrapper. In my current situation the attribute approach you've posted is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve the result you require with an open generic implementation and override specific default values as required. I.e. you define an open generic implementation `CachePolicy<TQuery>` of `ICachePolicy<TQuery>` and use the `RegisterInitializer` method to override parts of the default implementation.

Given these definitions:

```
public interface ICachePolicy<TQuery>
{
    DateTime AbsoluteExpiration { get; }
}

public class CachePolicy<TQuery> : ICachePolicy<TQuery>
{
    public CachePolicy()
    {
        AbsoluteExpiration = Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration;
    }

    public DateTime AbsoluteExpiration { get; set; }
}

public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> { }
public class QueryHandlerA : IQueryHandler<A, AResult> { }
public class QueryHandlerB : IQueryHandler<B, BResult> { }

public sealed class CachingQueryHandlerDecorator<TQuery, TResult>
    : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> decorated;
    public readonly ICachePolicy<TQuery> Policy;

    public CachingQueryHandlerDecorator(
        IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> decorated,
        ICachePolicy<TQuery> cachePolicy)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
        this.Policy = cachePolicy;
    }
}
```

Set up the container using the `RegisterOpenGeneric` method and configure the non default values using `RegisterInitializer`:

```
public Container ConfigureContainer()
{
    Container container = new Container();

    container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
        typeof(ICachePolicy<>), 
        typeof(CachePolicy<>), 
        Lifestyle.Singleton);

    container.RegisterInitializer<CachePolicy<A>>(a =>
        a.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));

    container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
        typeof(IQueryHandler<,>),
        typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).Assembly);

    container.RegisterDecorator(
        typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), 
        typeof(CachingQueryHandlerDecorator<,>));

    container.Verify();

    return container;
}
```

These tests demonstrate the result is as expected:

```
[Test]
public void GetInstance_A_HasCustomAbsoluteExpiration()
{
    Container container = ConfigureContainer();

    var a = container.GetInstance<IQueryHandler<A, AResult>>();

    Assert.AreNotEqual(
        (a as CachingQueryHandlerDecorator<A, AResult>).Policy.AbsoluteExpiration,
        Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration);
}

[Test]
public void GetInstance_B_HasDefaultAbsoluteExpiration()
{
    Container container = ConfigureContainer();

    var b = container.GetInstance<IQueryHandler<B, BResult>>();

    Assert.AreEqual(
        (b as CachingQueryHandlerDecorator<B, BResult>).Policy.AbsoluteExpiration,
        Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration);
}
```

Comment: Nice! I like how you used the `RegisterInitializer` to do this :-)

Comment: Thanks @qujck, the `RegisterInitializer` is something I haven't seen yet - I'm a bit new at using SimpleInjector.